# iCloud storage doesn't add up

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

As you can see here, my iCloud storage doesn't add up. This also shows the same on my iPhone.
[image][image][image] As you can see, Backups still takes up 3.86 GB of space, even though I deleted it (because i had no space left to backup, deleting the current backup usually allows me to do a new full backup). What can I do to restore my iCloud space?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little late but I had the same problem. Went to the genius bar and they said to call Apple Care. I called Apple Care three times. The first two people said that there are other item which could be taking up space and couldn't provide a solution. The third one was more experienced and fixed the problem within minutes. She had access to the "iCloud support tools". This is a tool the Apple iCloud team has access to (but we as consumers don't). She used the iCloud storage repair kit and within minutes, my devices refreshed and the free space showed up. Apparently this problem occurs when you upload a file, it gets corrupted, then once deleted, iCloud doesn't recognise the space as being free. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

There are other things besides apps that use up iCloud storage space.   The biggest is iMessage.   If you have conversations you haven't deleted in a while, especially ones with pictures, those take up quite a bit of space as part of your backups.

Also, it appears you have your mail backed up to iCloud as well (based on your screenshots).   Mail takes up space as well...  especially if you don't delete all your mail, or clear it from your trash.

Most likely, though, you haven't deleted your messages in some time and those are taking up the majority of your backup space.

EDIT - Also, since iMessages doesn't show up in the backup section (even though it is backed up), if you are curious as to how much space your messages are taking up, on your iPhone you can navigate to Settings -> General -> Storage & iCloud Usage -> Manage Storage (the one at the top under Storage).   From here, it will show how much space each app takes up on your phone.   Whatever you see here for messages, that will also affect your backup.

Comment: My messages is only at 100MB, and Mail is only at 10MB. The backup I deleted was 3.6GB, so I don't understand why I didn't get that space back.